# Getting the balance of a token in wallet - decimal issue

Tags: uniswap, ethers.js, pancakeswap

Im trying to get the balance of a certain token from a wallet address in order to then swap out those tokens. The problem i have is that the code returns the tokens where the decimal point is out which i assume is throwing my transaction into an error. Funny thing is that on some tokens (pancakeswap tokens) it works but on very low value tokens it fails.

```
const contractAddress = '0x....';
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(wssAddress);
const abi = ["function balanceOf(walletAddress) view returns (uint256)"];
const newContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress,abi,provider);
const balance = await shitContract.balanceOf('walletAddress');
```

Now if for example my token balance is 39,650,063.701257552

In ethers.js a console log of balance would look like this:

```
    console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));
    //result 0.039650063701257552
```

Answer (score 2):

`ethers.utils.formatEther` uses decimals as 18. Though most of popular ERC20 tokens out there use 18 decimals, there are some ERC20s that can use a different decimal value, like in your case it appears to be 9.

You can use the formatUnits, which allows passing in a decimal value.

```js
console.log(ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance, 9));
//result 39650063.701257552
```

How would you get decimal value of a token?

```js
const abi = [
  "function balanceOf(walletAddress) view returns (uint256)",
  "function decimals() view returns (uint256)"
];
const newContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress,abi,provider);
const decimals = await shitContract.decimals();
```

Comment: I think you meant you replace that last line with newContract lol.